# How to remove extra space due to padding or top properties

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need show image on top of a div by 50% and i use combination of css to make it work duet to `top: -100px;` it add extra area below the title & subtitle which i dont want

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JLBxBP

```css
.main-wrapper{ position:relative; width:100%; height:100%; margin:0 auto;background-color:yellow;}
.content-wrapper{ height:500px; background-color:blue; max-width:1070px;}

.gb-red{background-color:#f00;}
.gb-green{background-color:green;}

.cover-image-w{position:relative;z-index:2;}
.center-img {margin: 0 auto; max-height:250px; z-index:2;}
.titles-w {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 1;
 background-color: #EFEFEF;
 min-height: 125px;
 border-top: 125px solid yellow;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 top: -100px;
}
.titles-w  > h1 { font-size:18px; width:100%; text-align:center;font-weight:600; margin:5px 0 5px 0;}
.titles-w  > h2 { font-size:15px; width:100%; text-align:center; margin:10px 0 5px 0;}
```

```html
 <div class="main-wrapper">
    <div class="container content-wrapper"> 
      <div class="row"> 
       <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-sm-push-7 gb-red">
       <div class="cover-image-w">
      <img class="img-responsive center-img" src="https://topbackgroundwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/images-mobile-wallpaper-1200-swan-l.jpg" alt="">
      
     </div>
     <div class="titles-w">
      <h1>TITLE HERE</h1>
      <h2>SU TITLE</h2>
     </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-sm-pull-5 gb-green">
        <div class="latest-art-w">
      <h1>Trump threatens tariffs on Chinese industrial goods</h1>
      <p>Duties of 25% planned for products as ranging from robots asdasdand trains to snowblowers. Duties of 25% planned for products ranging from robots and trains to snowblowers. Duties of 25% planned for products ranging from robots and trains to snowblowers Duties of 25% planned for products ranging from robots and trains to snowblowers</p>
     </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
       </div>
```

Not sure how to get remove extra space as in this case.

IMAGE illustration [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `top: -100px` with `margin-top: -100px` so the height of the parent element will be properly calculated.

In fact if you move an element with `top` (or `left/right/bottom`) and with a `relative` position this won't affect or recalculate the surrounding space of its parent container (which will be calculated as the element was in `static` position).

Comment: What if height is dynamic then it will be hard to calculate..

Comment: I am trying to copy ft.com HTML structure looks completed, it adjust dynamically in proportion to left column also. which is nice. not sure how they have done it

Answer (score 0):

You can add a negative margin to the `.titles-w` element to reduce the space underneath. For example:

```
.titles-w {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
    min-height: 125px;
    border-top: 125px solid yellow;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    top: -100px;
    margin-bottom: -100px;
}
```

See https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WzKPVy. You may want to increase the margin to say `-85px` to maintain the red border effect.

Comment: I am trying to copy ft.com HTML structure looks completed, it adjust dynamically in proportion to let column also